# Terraform: New Relic Provider - Slack Notification Chann

Tags: terraform, slack, newrelic

Looking for a good example or list of inputs to provide for a Terraform script to create a **New Relic Slack Alert Channel**. The only example I have found was in the Terraform docs, but for email.

Taking a guess here, but Slack probably has different

```
# Add a notification channel
resource "newrelic_alert_channel" "email" {
  name = "email"
  type = "email"

  configuration = {
    recipients              = "paul@example.com"
    include_json_attachment = "1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resource [newrelic_alert_channel](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/newrelic/r/alert_channel.html) does support type of `slack`.

> type - (Required) The type of channel. One of: campfire, email, hipchat, opsgenie, pagerduty, slack, victorops, or webhook.

Refer: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-newrelic/blob/c1b47912aae73dffc2dbab8b7082ae46942aa8f9/newrelic/resource_newrelic_alert_channel.go#L37-L40

```
"slack": {
    "channel",
    "url",
},
```

I didn't test, but will this code work?

```
resource "newrelic_alert_channel" "slack" {
  name = "alerts"
  type = "slack"

  configuration = {
    channel = "alerts"
    url     = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/***********"
  }
}
```